# Does "alloc" methods produce an instance ?

Tags: objective-c

When I write:

```
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc]init];
```

I can split in 2 parts:

- `[MyClass alloc]` --->> produce something
- `[theProduct init];`

So alloc is a Class methods and being init an instance method i suppose that it must be called on an instance...in this case the result of `[MyClass alloc]`. 
I'm really confused about that.

Are my conjectures correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+alloc` allocates and zeroes the memory for an instance of a class. This instance is *uninitialized*—it's not ready to be used as an object until you initialize it with `-init` or related.

Answer (score 0):

Familiar with C++? `+alloc` = `new`. `-init…` = constructor method.